# Generate mesh from picture

Tags: graphics, finite-element-method, regions, mesh

It is probably a stupid question, but I can't figure out how to generate a mesh from picture like this

```
Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Thin], FaceForm[LightGray], 
   Rectangle[{-3, -2}, {3, 2}]}, {Circle[{0, 0}, 1.]}, {EdgeForm[
    Thin], FaceForm[White], Disk[{0, 0}, .5]}}]
```

[image]

where the white disk is actually a hole. The circle disappeared in all my attempts.

Comment: Not sure whether I fully understand, do you want to mesh the grey annulus (between radius 0.5 and 1) separately from the rest of the rectangle? If so then using `DiscretizeRegion` together with `ImplicitRegion` could be useful i.e.: `mesh1 = DiscretizeRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[((-3 <= x <= 3) && (-2 <= y <= 2) && (x^2 + y^2 >= 
       1)), {x, y}] ];
mesh2 = DiscretizeRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[((x^2 + y^2 >= 0.5) && (x^2 + y^2 <= 1)), {x, y}] ];
Show[{mesh1, mesh2}]`

Comment: Why do you need the circle in the mesh?

Comment: I don't see that any of mathematicas built in mesh generation  ( `DiscretizeRegion` or `ToElementMesh` ) has capability to create a single mesh with such an internal edge. There certainly are reasons to do that of course.

Comment: I want to have one mesh with a circle which separates two regions of different properties. I've eventually found a solution using ToElementMesh and "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"Continuation"} and "RegionHoles" properties. But it's rather tricky, I still would like to have a more straightforward solution.

Comment: It will be helpful if you post the code you tried..

Answer (score 12):

I think this is a good question. Here's an example showing what I believe is the desired result, but using a laborious method specifying the boundary coordinates and line elements explicitly.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

rectanglepoints = {{-3, -2}, {-3, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, -2}};
circlepoints = CirclePoints[1, 30];
holepoints = CirclePoints[0.5, 30];

bm = ToBoundaryMesh[
      "Coordinates" -> Join[rectanglepoints, circlepoints, holepoints],
      "BoundaryElements" -> {
     LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}}], 
     LineElement[Partition[4 + Range[1, 30], 2, 1, {1, 1}]],
     LineElement[Partition[34 + Range[1, 30], 2, 1, {1, 1}]]}];

em = ToElementMesh[bm, "RegionHoles" -> {0, 0}, "RegionMarker" -> {{0, 0.75}, 1}];

em["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> {FaceForm[Green], FaceForm[Red]}]]
```

[image]

There must surely be a better way, to generate the mesh from `Rectangle` and `Annulus` regions.

Answer (score 7):

I once helped someone with something similar from a micrograph.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8B1D.jpg"];

cleaned = Thinning@ColorNegate@Binarize[img, 0.7];
imgComp = MorphologicalComponents[cleaned];
imgComp // Colorize
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
SortBy[Tally[Flatten[imgComp]], Last]
{innerCircle, outerCircle, bdyRect, backgroundComp} = %[[All, 1]]
(*
  {{3, 163}, {2, 325}, {1, 1146}, {0, 86566}}
  {3, 2, 1, 0}
*)

outerPos = N@PixelValuePositions[Image@imgComp, outerCircle];
innerPos = N@PixelValuePositions[Image@imgComp, innerCircle];
bdyPos = N@PixelValuePositions[Image@imgComp, bdyRect];
```

I down-sample the circles, which is optional (see the mesh visualization below to adjust as needed).

```
outer = SortBy[outerPos, ArcTan @@ (# - Mean[outerPos]) &][[;; ;; 5]];
inner = SortBy[innerPos, ArcTan @@ (# - Mean[innerPos]) &][[;; ;; 5]];

Length /@ {outer, inner}
(*  {65, 33, 1146}  *)

corners = ImageCorners@Image[imgComp /. x_ /; x > 1 -> 0]
(*  {{350.5, 9.5}, {350.5, 235.5}, {9.5, 235.5}, {9.5, 9.5}}  *)

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> Join[outer, inner, corners],
    "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[
      Partition[Append[Range[Length@outer], 1], 2, 1, 1]], 
     LineElement[
      Partition[Append[Length@outer + Range[Length@inner], Length@outer + 1], 
       2, 1, 1]],
     LineElement[
      Partition[Append[Length@outer + Length@inner + Range[Length@corners], 
                 Length@outer + Length@inner + 1],
       2, 1, 1]]}];

mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh,
  "RegionHoles" -> Mean /@ {MinMax@corners[[All, 1]], MinMax@corners[[All, 2]]}
  ];

Show[
 mesh["Wireframe"],
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", "MeshElementStyle" -> Red]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Without down-sampling:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Sorry for necroing. If my micrograph was more complicated (multiple islands etc.) would I still be able to mesh it using the same way you have done here?

Comment: To clarify the main issue I am having (I think) is that the perimeter coordinates I am getting from MorphologicalPerimeter is not sorted correctly - it is discretised over the X axis rather than by connected points. Should I make a new question for this?

Comment: @Zhao It's probably better to ask a new question.  I don't have any general advice based on your description, plus there are others on this site who are much more experienced with image processing than I am.

Answer (score 5):

I am still not sure what is the expected output. But you could try ImageMesh function:

```
picture = 
 Graphics[{{Thickness[.005], Circle[{0, 0}, 1.]}, Disk[{0, 0}, .5]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

```
ImageMesh[picture, Method -> "MarchingSquares"]
```

[image]